# Remove all numerical values from a string

Tags: arrays, string, awk

I have an array (vars) in awk which includes a set of strings made of numbers and alphabets( e.g. px0, px2 ...)
I want to split these string into numbers and alphabets and put them into another two dimensional array(comp)

```
 vars[i]={px0,px2,...}-> comp[i,1]={px,px,...},comp[i,2]={0,2,...}
```

`px0   ->px, 0

 px2   ->px, 2 
 py4   ->py, 4 
 dxy17 ->dxy,17`

I have tried to use sub function and put the results in to a new array,

```
for (k=l; k<=length(vars); k++){
    j=j+1;vars2[k]=vars[k];
    sub(/[a-z]/,"",vars2[k])
    comp[j,2]=vars2[k]
    printf comp[j,2]
    printf " "
    sub(/[0-9]/,"",vars[k])
    comp[j,1]=vars[k]
    print comp[j,1]
}
```

but the sub only removes one character from the string.

```
px0 -> px, x0
```

Comment: Please post samples of input and output in your post in code tags.

Comment: I indented code for you, but next time, thanks to do it yourself, it's a bit of respect for readers/anwerers

Comment: Having a good reputation of 150+ you should start using code tags now in your post, please post samples of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry I kept getting an error that I'm not using code tags while I was clicking on it. my bad

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi, add samples of input and expected output too in your post.

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi, what is the need of using a bash array in `awk` if you could provide us the sample Input_file and what is your actual expected output there could be a chance we could do it within a single `awk` itself, let us know complete details on same.

Comment: This is a part of really long script. In this part I read the arguments which the user apply to run the script, I used an array cause the user may enter as many inputs as s/he may like. The input is the pxy0 etc

Comment: It makes no difference to us that this is part of a really long script. Create a small script with it's own sample input/output that demonstrates your problem (i.e. a [mcve]) and include that in your question if you'd like help coming up with a good solution. Otherwise if you get any answer at all then it's likely to be some half-backed nonsense that does what you think it should do but is really completely wrong for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the major thing needed in the attempt is to specify `+` in the `/[0-9]+/` match.  Here is an alternative version which matches and deletes the numbers leaving the string behind.

```
#! /usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
    split("", vars)
    vars[1] = "px0"
    vars[2] = "px2"
    vars[3] = "py4"
    vars[4] = "dxy17"

    print "vars[i]={px0,px2,...}-> comp[i,1]={px,px,...},comp[i,2]={0,2,...}"
    print ""

    split("", comp)
    sz = length(vars)
    for (i = 1; i <= sz; ++i) {
        v = vars[i]
        if (match(v, /[0-9]+/))
            sub(comp[i,2] = substr(v, RSTART, RLENGTH), "", v)
        comp[i,1] = v
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= sz; ++i)
        printf("%-6s->%-4s%d\n", vars[i], comp[i,1] ",", comp[i,2])
}
```

And output:

```
vars[i]={px0,px2,...}-> comp[i,1]={px,px,...},comp[i,2]={0,2,...}

px0   ->px, 0
px2   ->px, 2
py4   ->py, 4
dxy17 ->dxy,17
```

Alternative implementations:

We could alternatively find the string part and delete to leave the numeric behind, or we could use two different matches and just drop the results of each in comp[]... but in any case the `if (match()) x = substr()` pattern (which is *POSIX*) is our friend.

If we are using **gawk**, **gawk** automatically provides the `substr()` for us if we supply `match()` an additional parameter `a` -- the substr() will be dropped into `a[0]`.  Additionally, **gawk** stuffs a lot of functionality into that extra parameter, and learning about it is worth a dive into the **man** page.